# Eigen Use in ios project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, vector, eigen

I am trying to use Eigen 3 in my ios project i have added header files but it does not allow me to compile. it always gives error.

Unable to resolve. I have been searching for solutions for many days.

My All files are .mm

I think, i am missing any compiler flag, linking or anyting.

Please help me.

Attached screen shots of Xcode.

I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure you are including Eigen/Core (or the likes) and not directly the .h files that are in Eigen/src/. Then, I guess the problem is that your are mixing c++ and objective c code (.mm file). That confuse the compiler because Eigen requires a very good C++ compiler support. Cannot you use pure C++ code in ios?

Comment: I hope you could write a tutorial how you made it work. I am still seeing the similar issues.

Comment: You can compile and use pure C++ code in ios projects (I do it). I create wrapper Obj-C++ / .mm files around it tp act as "bridge." Evidently Xcode 15 has a more direct method for this now, but I have my trepidation using it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The error statements are quite clear: you use identifiers that are not known to the compiler.
Possible reasons:

1. You failed to include the proper header files. E.g., `Dynamic` is defined in `Constants.h`
2. You failed to open the proper namespace. E.g., `Dynamic` is defined for the namespace `Eigen`.

Comment: but this is default Eigen Header file libraries. It should not give these type of errors.
This is Block.h file

and even it is giving error: Block is undeclared.

Comment: If this is a header of Eigen (you should have mentioned that), I guess the errors you displayed are not the first ones, are they? Check your include paths and the lines **before** you include Eigen.

Comment: I am working on pure c++ code in my project. but connecting that c++ code objective-c for iOS.
Xcode basic compiler and i have set paths to Eigen as well. Yes  used (.mm) and include Eigen/Core not the files in src.

but still error..

Answer (score 0):

My code was working fine until I added an opencv header, then these popped up.

The solution was to add eigen and eigen/unsupported to System Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths, and leave them as non-recursive.

You definitely want to mark your .cpp file as Objective C++ too.